# How can I open a python GUI in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a graphic project for my programming class and the teacher wants us to use graphics.py (can be found at https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) as a "training wheel" for tkinter. I was using CS50 IDE (cs50.ide.io) and would just click the GUI button and run my code to see my graphic.
EDIT: I also tried just running the code in IDLE and it worked fine.

I'm using VS Code now and whenever I run my program, I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/64099811/python/graphics/christmas.py", line 2, in <module>
    from graphics import *
  File "/workspaces/64099811/python/graphics/graphics.py", line 185, in <module>
    _root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Here's my code. Just a note, you do need to have graphics.py in the same folder for it to work.

```
from graphics import *

canvas = GraphWin('christmas',1000, 500)
canvas.setBackground(color_rgb(24, 94, 125))
floor = Rectangle (Point(0,500), Point(1000, 360))
floor.setFill(color_rgb(111, 60, 64))
floor.draw(canvas)
```

Here's the link to a document with the commands from graphics.py: https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf
This is what CS50 IDE looks like: [CS50 IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSrJh.png)

Comment: @Adid In my code or in the graphics.py file?  I rather only make changes in my code if possible.

Comment: Is vscode connected to a remote workspace that doesn't have a display?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It was.  I was using VS Code with Github Codespaces.  My code runs fine in regular VS Code.  Do you know how to connect a display to a Codespace?

Comment: that would mean running Tk in a browser, that will not happen, run a python interpreter in a native terminal, the terminal in the Codespace is a tunneled stdin/stdout to a python interpreter running on the server

Comment: @rioV8 So is there any way I can use tk with Codespaces?

Comment: It's not possible. The GUI would have to appear on the remote server